# Could not perform submodule update

Tags: git

In jenkins (Linux), git submodule init error like this, but it can work in Git Extensions (windows).

- Update tracking submodules to tip of branch
- Use credentials from default remote of parent repository

```java
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git submodule update --init --recursive --remote xmbank # timeout=10
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git submodule update --init --recursive --remote xmbank" returned status code 1:
stdout: Cloning into 'xmbank'...

stderr: error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 404
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Clone of 'http://161.63.240.154/app/F-DIG/apps/xmbank' into submodule path 'xmbank' failed

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2436)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2050)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$7.lambda$execute$0(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1459)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:253)
    at java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService.submit(ExecutorCompletionService.java:181)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.cgit.GitCommandsExecutor.submitRemainingCommand(GitCommandsExecutor.java:75)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.cgit.GitCommandsExecutor.invokeAll(GitCommandsExecutor.java:64)
Caused: hudson.plugins.git.GitException
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.cgit.GitCommandsExecutor.checkResult(GitCommandsExecutor.java:87)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.cgit.GitCommandsExecutor.invokeAll(GitCommandsExecutor.java:68)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.cgit.GitCommandsExecutor.invokeAll(GitCommandsExecutor.java:47)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$7.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1462)
    at hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.SubmoduleOption.onCheckoutCompleted(SubmoduleOption.java:159)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Could not perform submodule update
    at hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.SubmoduleOption.onCheckoutCompleted(SubmoduleOption.java:164)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1259)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:505)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1206)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1856)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
```

Answer (score 7):

I added `.git` suffix to the URL and it's ok，

`.gitmodules`

before：

```
[submodule "xmbank"]
    path = xmbank
    url = http://161.63.240.154/app/F-DIG/apps/xmbank
```

after：

```
[submodule "xmbank"]
    path = xmbank
    url = http://161.63.240.154/app/F-DIG/apps/xmbank.git
```